# QRCode scanner for devices with bad camera

Tags: android, zxing

In my app i need to read qrcode. For this i'm using zxing journeyapp barcode scanner. It works for perfectly on devices, which have a good camera, something like sony z3 and same it. But on devices, which have a camera with 1.3 mp i have trouble to read qr code. I tried to set specific setting like this:

```
    final Map<DecodeHintType, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    Set<BarcodeFormat> formats = EnumSet.noneOf(BarcodeFormat.class);
    formats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    mScanner.getBarcodeView().setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(formats, map, "CHARACTER_SET"));
```

When i tried to scan my qrcode with other apps from ggogle play it works nice, but not in my app. Also i tried zXingScannerView to resolve this issue, but it works same. Does anyone have ideas how to fix it?

Comment: User this lib to better performance https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

Comment: @Himani it doesn't help

Comment: it works fine for me